# git pull/merge between base application project and specific client project

Tags: git

I have a git repository containg the base code for my application. Lets say a client wants some specific customizations for the app. I want to be able to clone the git repo into a new project with the specific changes for that client. The problem is: I want to be able to fix bugs and add global updates to my base application and merge that changes into each client application.

What do you think is the best way to this?

**EDIT:** Maybe instead of a new project for each client i can create a branch? Can I merge back and forth between branches that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have a "common" branch, that is ideally a product in its own right but can be just a base for different customizations.

From that you branch off "client1", and make the changes. Same for other clients. Just the custom things. Do most work on the common, and keep merging it to all customized branches.

If you can keep the custom stuff in a single commit (or just a few), you can instead keep rebasing those on top of common, that way is easier to look through. Which is better depends on the actual workflow and nature/amount of differences.